# window.onload not working always in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I have two radio button in my views. on Page load i want to trigger a click event, i used the following Jquery Code to click radio button on page load.

```
 $(window).on("load", function () {
        jQuery(function () {
            jQuery('#addressID_radioButton').click();
            jQuery('#personID_radioButton').click(); 
        });
    });
```

But in Chrome  `jQuery('#addressID_radioButton').click();` works or triggers click event on `addressID_radioButton` radio button but on `jQuery('#personID_radioButton').click();`  sometime it works sometimes it doesn't, i have to refresh the page to make it work.

Comment: Have you console.log to see if your even getting to the one that is not working?

Comment: @chewie when i past this ` jQuery('#personID_radioButton').click();` in console it works on trigger click

Comment: try using trigger('clcik')

Comment: also do you have any event listeners for the clicks ?   else you could your prop('checked',ture)

Comment: ahh just like the answer below

Comment: It could work well in my project.Did you have any other js in your project?Maybe before click it did other operations and make error or conflict with your seconf click event?

Comment: @Rena yes, i have, let me add them see if you see the issue

Comment: @Rena i added more code and screenshot, on browser the debugger code on the second function it pauses and when i click on resume it works

Answer (score 0):

Set checked instead if that is all you are wanting to accomplish

```
jQuery('#addressID_radioButton, #personID_radioButton').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried it now both not working you mean with out windw.load?

Comment: Depends where you run this. Also if it's not working perhaps those elements are loaded by ajax? If `console.log(jQuery('#addressID_radioButton, #personID_radioButton').length)` is zero they don't exist yet

Comment: `console.log(jQuery('#addressID_radioButton, #personID_radioButton').length)` display 1 added after the function

Comment: Should be 2 though

Comment: chrome displays 2  firefox display 1 , and  firfox displays 0 then after refresh displays two same record chrom displays 2

Comment: Hard to help any more without a [mcve] that demonstrates issue

Answer (score 0):

Since updating to Wordpress 5.6 I've noticed $(window).on("load"... is very fickle. I installed jQuery migrate too.

Try document.ready to test and I think you'll find it will work.

I'm not sure if the $(window).on("load" bug is related to jQuery or browser.